# How can I stop the service using a toggle button in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently implementing an accelerometer in service which is run in background system. I want to stop and start the service on toggle button which is used in another Activity. When I start the Application my service is start and there toggle button is on in another activity.So how can I get this point? How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide with what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Your_service_class.class));
```

Does it work?